# finds the documents which are created 5 years ago

Tags: mongodb-query

I have to find documents which are created 5 years ago.

This query is returning everything.

```
db.col.find({
"createdDate":{
    '$gte':new Date(new Date().setYear(new Date().getYear()-5))}
    });
```

I searched around and found it for sql,

```
select * from table1 where b > YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 5;
```

I want something similar in mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect method - getYear()

> A number representing the year of the given date, according to local
>   time, minus 1900.

Returns 113

So `new Date().getYear()-5 => 113`

```
new Date(new Date().setYear(113) => 0113-03-16T01:35:13.251Z
```

Fix:

Use getFullYear() instead.

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setYear(dt.getFullYear()-5);
db.col.find({ "createdDate":{'$gte':dt}});
```